# Comparing TextBox values without arrays. C#

Tags: c#

I have a basic program with 26 TextBoxes named `textBox1` to `textBox26` and a button. The button currently gives a value of `1`,`x` or `2` to each TextBox. I also want it to compare the values of a TextBox and the one with a name contaning a number 13 greater than the last without using an array or multiple if/else statements. For example I want to compare `textBox1` with `textBox14`. I currently have this code:

```
Random r = new Random();
int ran;
int x;
int y;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control b in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        ran = r.Next(1, 4);
        if (ran == 1)
        {
            b.Text = "1";
        }
        else if (ran == 2)
        {
            b.Text = "x";
        }
        else if (ran == 3)
        {
            b.Text = "2";
        }

        x = b.TabIndex;
        y = x + 13;

        var box = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + x.ToString());
        var box1 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + y.ToString());

        box.Text = box1.Text;
    }
}
```

This gives the the error message:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'search Children' of 'Control.ControlCollection.Find(string, bool)'
>   on the lines with:

```
var box = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + x.ToString());
var box1 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + y.ToString());
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use an array here?  It would be better since it would refactor better (imagine if you decided to give the text boxes more meaningful names).

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  What is the ultimate goal of these comparisons?

Answer (score 2):

Your specific error is because you're not providing a value for the argument (as the error states...):

```
var box = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + x.ToString(), false);
```

Use `false`, as in my example, or `true` depending on your needs.  Do you want the search to include controls (i.e. children) that are nested inside the controls you are searching?

Comment: If it helps me compare the values of the textboxes in the program that I'm running then yes, I would like it to include the controls the are nested inside the controls being searched. My idea is to compare them like this:

                if (box.Text == box1.Text)
                {
                    box.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    box.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }